Publishing a book directly on the Internet
I want the last two books I've written to exist only as Internet links (as php files)—no registration, no printed text, just links—follow the link and start reading for free. But here's the problem. None of the known book sites, such as Amazon and GoodReads, allow access without registration. They also don't seem to allow posting a direct link to a book, rather than having it as a pdf or already printed. On the other hand, I feel very uncomfortable posting links to my books as posts in discussions on Twitter (I don't use Facebook and would like to keep it that way) or on forums, literary or non-literary, their registration requirements notwithstanding. I also tried other avenues, to no avail. I wrote to the local branch of the New York Public Library—the manager didn't respond to my email. Has anyone had any experience with this type of publication, completely free and directly accessible on the Internet?

I’m voting to close this question because Literature Stack Exchange is for discussing pre-existing literature, not helping writers publish their own literature.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. As @bobble says in their comment, your question does not quite meet our site's remit. You might have better luck at Writing Stack Exchange; this question appears to be in line with the questions tagged publishing there.
